# Making an "and" statement to match more than 1 value

Tags: powershell

I got this part of a script

```
| Where {$_.property = statement}
```

I would like to add another value so that it has to match both values, so the command is going to work kinda like this

```
| Where {$_.property -eq statement} &  {$_.anotherproperty -eq anotherstatement}
```

anyone who can help?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Logical and is done using `-and` in powershell:

```
| Where {$_.property -eq statement -and $_.anotherproperty -eq anotherstatement}
```

Comment: Is it really that easy? :) - Thanks Lee

Answer (score 4):

The syntax you are looking for is `-and` and `-or`.

This example prints "Hello" if the variable `a` is greater than 9 and less than 11.

```
$a = 10
if ($a -gt 9 -and $a -lt 11) { Write-Host "Hello" }
```

Please see the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347738.aspx) for more details.